# How can I update this JSON with TextFields?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, material-ui

I have a group of TextFields within a material-ui dialog.  The textFields are populated by JSON, and example of which can be seen below.  As it is now, I can populate TextFields, but I cannot update them.  I cannot enter any more text into these TextFields after they have been populated.

This is how my TextFields look

```
    const [singleSizing, setSingleSizing] = useState("");

    const SizingTextFields = ({ val, label, disabled, select }) => {
        return (
            <TextField
                value={val}
                label={label}
                variant="outlined"
                onChange={(e) => updateSingleSizing(e.target.value)}
                style={{ margin: "1em", minHeight: "1em", minWidth: "15em" }}
                select={select}
                disabled={disabled}
            />
        );
    };

    function updateSingleSizing(newData) {
        for (var i = 0; i < singleSizing.length; i++) {
            if (singleSizing[i].Domain !== newData) return singleSizing[i].Domain === newData;
            if (singleSizing[i].Experience !== newData) return singleSizing[i].Experience === newData;
            if (singleSizing[i].SizingContact !== newData) return singleSizing[i].SizingContact === newData;
            if (singleSizing[i].SizingComments !== newData) return singleSizing[i].SizingComments === newData;
        }
    }
```

My JSON example:

```
{
  "Domain": "Stack Overflow",
  "Experience": "SO",
  "SizingContact": "Ciaran Crowley",
  "SizingComments": "Test update 2"
}
```

Comment: In the `onChange` event, you are returning something but not updating it. Could you please share working code in codesandbox?

Comment: [Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/hopeful-mahavira-f2kmwy?file=/src/App.js) is the code sandbox link

Comment: What is happening in `UpdateSingleSizing` function? Is it updates the object or it is just for comparison?

Comment: I am trying to update the JSON Object seen in this question.  That is what I am trying to do in ``updateSingleSizing``

Answer (score 1):

The `singleSizing` object is not updated when the text changes from the `TextField`'s `onChange` event. The `updateSingleSizing` function just returns the new values but it doesn't update the `singleSizing` object.

So we need a function to update the `singleSizing` object. The `onTextChange` function updates the `singleSizing` object (more about [spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) syntax) when the `TextField` text changes.

```
    const onTextChange = (e) => {
    const id = e.target.id;
    const value = e.target.value;
    setSingleSizing({
      ...singleSizing,
      [id]: value
    });
  };
```

And the TextFields updated with `id` property to update the actual property of `singleSizing` object.

```
          <SizingTextFields
            id="taxonomyId"
            val={singleSizing.taxonomyId}
            label={"Taxonomy Id"}
          />
          <SizingTextFields
            id="domain"
            val={singleSizing.domain}
            label={"Domain"}
          />
          <SizingTextFields
            id="experience"
            val={singleSizing.experience}
            label={"Experience"}
          />
....
```

Also, the `TextField`'s `select` property expects child component and options. So the `SizingTextFields` function updated with child component.

```
const SizingTextFields = ({
    id,
    val,
    label,
    disabled,
    select = false,
    options = []
  }) => {
    return select ? (
      <TextField
        id={id}
        value={val}
        label={label}
        variant="outlined"
        onChange={onTextChange}
        style={{ margin: "1em", minHeight: "1em", minWidth: "15em" }}
        select
        SelectProps={{
          native: true
        }}
        disabled={disabled}
      >
        {options.map((option) => (
          <option key={option.value} value={option.value}>
            {option.label}
          </option>
        ))}
      </TextField>
    ) : (
      <TextField
        id={id}
        value={val}
        label={label}
        variant="outlined"
        onChange={onTextChange}
        style={{ margin: "1em", minHeight: "1em", minWidth: "15em" }}
        disabled={disabled}
      />
    );
  };
```

The updated codesandbox

[image: Edit SO-72375315-Answer]

Comment: Thanks you very much Selva.  I have another issue now.  When I enter one character into a TextField, my ``Dialog`` disappears and reappears.  Focus is lost on the TextField when this happens, but the character entered is persistent

Comment: A similar issue is present in your code sandbox where after entering one character into a textField, focus on that textField is lost.

Answer (score 0):

You should use **setSingleSizing** function to update your state.
You should not mutate your state directly as in your updateSingleSizing function.
Also you are returning a boolean by using the === operator. Try something like this (I am not impelmenting your array logic.)

```
onChange={(e) => setSingleSizing(e.target.value)}
```

Comment: I tried this.  When I enter more than one character into any of the TextFields, the dialog seems to be re-rendered with empty Textfields.